# Unsure of $|A \times A|$ vector notation in quantum informatics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, vectors, notation, density-operator

I am new to quantum informatics and am doing a course on it. The guy who runs the course keeps writing down this notation - $|0  \times 0|$ or $|1  \times 1|$ - although it is completely foreign to me. When I look it up or ask GPT it gives a vague answer and says that the notation is unclear, so I think I am translating it wrong. If anybody could help me out in what it means or is trying to say, it would be greatly appreciated!

[image: This is the general context]

[image: This |0 x 0|, |+ X +| notation is what is confusing me]

Comment: It is just that it is extremely difficult to write $\left|\psi\right>\left<\psi\right|$ beautifully every time, whereas it is extremely easy to write $\left|\psi\times\psi\right|$ beautifully.

Comment: Use MathJax, not images. Edit: okay, the problem here seems to be the handwriting..-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation you refer to is actually $| A \rangle \langle A |$, where the $\rangle \langle$ can be confused with the $\times$ symbol, when not properly written...

Comment: My prof would fight you. There was one bizarre lecture where he spent a good tenth of the time lecturing us that _this is the correct way to write it_

Comment: I think most people actually *do* write it the same way as an X, i.e., with two straight lines which cross. (Certainly, this is what I do. Then again, I *do* point out at the beginning of the lecture that this is not an X but a ket-bra-pair, as I know it leads to confusion otherwise.)